# Displaying email address of Linkedin User using passportjs

Tags: node.js, pug, passport.js

I am trying to retrieve the `email address, 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address','public-profile-url' and  profile pic`

however, it is not getting displayed. My code is as follows:

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({   
    consumerKey: LINKEDIN_API_KEY,
    consumerSecret: LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback",
    scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_basicprofile'],
    profileFields: ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address','public-profile-url'],    
    state: true    
    },
    function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log ("PROFILE "+profile.id, token, profile.displayName ,profile.emails[0].value);
        process.nextTick(function() {    
            return done(null,profile);                                
        });    
    })
);
```

Front end is on `JADE`.

```
if user
    | #{user.id}
    | #{user.r_emailaddress}
    a(href='/logout') logout with LinkedIn
```

Note: The `email address` doesn't get displayed nor does 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address','public-profile-url'. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to be find in the NodeJS backend side of the code. By replacing `#{user.r_emailaddress}` with `#{user.emails[0].value}`  gave me the primary email address of the user.